# ember-cli-blanket not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, blanket.js

I have installed the plugin for 'ember-cli-blanket', using command:

```
ember install:addon ember-cli-blanket0
```

But when I run the tests using "http://localhost:4200/tests", nothing is loading I am getting just a blank page, no error in console also.
When I referred in some online tutorials, they asked to pass "data-cover" with the `<script></script>` tag. But no progress.
If i uninstall the plugin and run the tests it is working fine.

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong or any more settings needs to be done?

Comment: I feel I may have seen this recently, are you certain you passed data-cover to the right script tag?    `<script src="assets/your-app-name.js" data-cover></script>`

Comment: Do the tests run (and do you get the coverage report) when you run `ember test --server`?